# Use hasOwnProperty with dot operator

Tags: javascript

I have one object `var tree={}` with attribute `tree.leaves.leaf={}`.

When I perform `tree.hasOwnProperty("leaves.leaf")` its giving `false` .

When I check `tree.hasOwnProperty("leaves")` and then `tree.leaves.hasOwnProperty("leaf")` it's working.

Can I use dot operator inside `hasOwnProperty()` function? How to do it?

Comment: How about {null: [1,2]}?

Comment: i have mentioned that i cant use array,i need the same order is that possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @taguenizy answer is working for me

Comment: You cannot use dot notation to access properties in subobjects the way you are trying to do, at least not without additional special machinery.

Comment: Do not replace one question with another one. Instead, delete the first question, and ask a new one.

Comment: ya but it was giving standard not met error for me,what is the error with this question?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use dot notation inside hasOwnProperty() function?

No, you can't.

By the way, the dot is not an "operator".